# Visual studio 2013 installation troubleshooting

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I had some problems with my VS2013 and I uninstlled it.

After I uninstlled VS2013 I restarted my computer, downloaded from Microsoft's website .exe file **Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Update 4**
and I started installation process.

On the installation process I get this window:

[image]

In the window above on, **Please provide a location to search for the packages**  text box I have this string:

```
C:\Users\userName\Downloads\packages\BuildTools_MSBuild_x86\BuildTools_MSBuild.msi
```

Any idea why I get this window and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you any versions of VS which was installed before?

Answer (score 5):

You mention that you are using the .exe file from the website to install your Visual Studio. The .exe file is an online installer which, based on what you choose to install, will selectively download the packages that you need. If the online installer has any problems downloading any of the packages, the installation will fail.

I would suggest you download the .iso, which contains an *offline* installer. The offline installer contains all the packages necessary to install Visual Studio with all the options, and can be burnt onto a DVD. The advantage of this is that once you have downloaded it, you can install it on as many computers as you want without needing to download the same files for each machine.

Try downloading the .iso installer for the version you want: this will remove the possibility that the installer was unable to download part of the package. Optionally, use the [File Checksum Integrity Verifier](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) tool to check it's downloaded successfully.

I've included links to both the standard and the Ultimate versions since you mention Professional in the text of your question and the image says Ultimate.

- Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4

  - [main download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44921)
  - [direct link to the .iso installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=512594).
- Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 4

  - [main download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44915)
  - [direct link to .iso installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=512616).

---

It looks like others have had your problem - I suspect your problem is the same as the problem in the social.msdn.microsoft.com thread [*Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 failing on Msi_BuildTools, "The hash value is not correct"*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae2918fb-c3b5-4e5d-aa4a-54eeaf312004/visual-studio-2013-update-1-failing-on-msibuildtools-the-hash-value-is-not-correct?forum=vssetup) which, while relating to 2013 Update 1, reads to me like the same problem. Using the .iso installer solved the problem there.

---

Note that Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 has also been released - you can get the online installer from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48129) or, if you have a Visual Studio account, you can download it from VisualStudio.com [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/).

Comment: I tried  to install few times VS2013 professional and VS2013 ultimate and all the time I get the same message.

Comment: Were you using an .iso (offline installer), or the .exe (online installer)?

Comment: I download .exe from microsoft site.

Comment: Try the .iso installers instead: for [pro](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=512594) / for [ultimate](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=512616).

Comment: @Any idea what is differance between .exe and .iso?

Comment: The .exe installer is an *online* installer: it's small (~2MB) and will download the packages while installing them. The advantage is that you can start installing much sooner. The .iso installer is an *offline* installer: it's much larger (~6-7GB) but means that once you download it, you can either copy the .iso to other computers, or burn it onto a DVD and install it many times without needing an internet connection. The results should be the same, but since you have problems with the online installer, I suggest the offline installer.

Comment: I download .iso file provided by your link.After I extract the files and press to install the visual studio I get this error:

Update 4 does not apply or is blocked by another condition on your computer

Comment: I think that's because you've extracted the .iso rather than mounting it. Which .iso did you download - normal, or ultimate? Also, can you [mount the .iso](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38780) instead of extracting it? Lastly, did you run the vs2013.4.exe file in the extracted .iso, or another?

Comment: the normal  version

Comment: Have you had any luck mounting the iso?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem while installing. I then clicked on

> Download packages from the internet

and the installer downloaded everything it needs from internet.

If you don't have any problem to download from internet, you can select that option and continue with installing

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues in the past, with VS2012/13/15 community & professional.

Invariably my issues were caused by me cancelling an install part-way through which failed to fully remove the product, and/or my attempts to uninstall VS which similarly leaves certain artifacts hanging around.

I resorted to full clean/resets of VS (e.g. [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720585.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) but since then I have become aware of [Microsoft's VS total uninstall app](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) which was created to overcome the very issue of standard uninstall leaving artifacts behind.

So although I've not used the [Microsoft uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) myself, I would certainly recommend giving it a try, and hopefully after that you will be able to install successfully.